# MySQL INSERT IF condition is true

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm making a stored routine in MySQL, and I would like to know whether it is possible to make an INSERT-IF some condition is TRUE, ELSE INSERT something else.

This is My Query but I keep getting the #1064 Error (SQL Syntax Error).

```
DECLARE a INT;
DECLARE b INT;
DECLARE changeTypeID INT DEFAULT(0);

SET a = (SELECT roomPrice FROM RPH WHERE tier=1 AND 
startDate = '2018-02-20' AND rTypeID=1);
SET b = (SELECT roomPrice FROM RPH WHERE tier=1 AND 
startDate = '2018-02-20' AND rTypeID=2);

SET changeTypeID = CASE WHEN (a>b) THEN 1 WHEN (a<b) THEN 2 WHEN a=b THEN 3 END;
IF (changeTypeID = 1 OR changeTypeID =2) THEN
(
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (X,Y,Z) VALUES (ID, changeTypeID, createdBy);
)
ELSEIF (changeTypeID = 3) THEN
(
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (P,Q,R) VALUES (ID, rID, createdBy);
)
END IF;
```

Here is the error message:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL version for the right syntax to use near
'INSERT INTO TABLE_A (X,Y,Z)' at line 19
```

Note: The insert parameter is already declared on the routine beforehand.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the precise error message? MySQL is usually extremely specific about what went wrong.

Comment: Is `typeID` declared?

Comment: I already included my error message, thanks for the advice.

Comment: semicolon missing at insert statement

Comment: Sorry, typeID is changeTypeID, I already edited the question

Comment: sorry I already tried add and removing the semicolon, it doesn't work. edited the question :)

Comment: Why are you using "("? You need not have brackets in if else loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE a INT;
DECLARE b INT;
DECLARE changeTypeID INT DEFAULT(0);

SET a = (SELECT roomPrice FROM RPH WHERE tier=1 AND 
startDate = '2018-02-20' AND rTypeID=1);
SET b = (SELECT roomPrice FROM RPH WHERE tier=1 AND 
startDate = '2018-02-20' AND rTypeID=2);

SET changeTypeID = CASE WHEN (a>b) THEN 1 WHEN (a<b) THEN 2 WHEN a=b THEN 3 END;
IF (changeTypeID = 1 OR changeTypeID =2) THEN

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (X,Y,Z) VALUES (ID, changeTypeID, createdBy);

ELSEIF (changeTypeID = 3) THEN

INSERT INTO TABLE_B (P,Q,R) VALUES (ID, rID, createdBy);

END IF;
```

Comment: oh my God that is so simple! thank you for your help :)